# Sencha Touch 2 array parsing

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha touch and I'm trying to parse an array of data (this doesn't seem like an uncommon use case but I can't find anything about it online).  I followed the sencha ext.data.reader.json doc on nested json, but it doesn't work.  Here are my models:
Search Results (to hold multiple search results):

```
Ext.define('GS.model.SearchResults', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
autoLoad: true,
config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'query', type: 'string'},
    ],
    hasMany  : {model: 'SearchResult', name: 'results'},

        }
});
```

And search result, to hold an individual search result

```
Ext.define('GS.model.SearchResult', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',     type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',      type: 'string'}
    ],
    belongsTo: 'SearchResults'
}
});
```

Then in my controller, I have this code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: "true",
        model: "GS.model.SearchResults",
        proxy: 
        {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'www.someurl.com/?query=somequery',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load({
        callback: function() {
            console.log("Done Loading");
            var root = store.first();

            console.log("Results for " + root.get('query')); //this prints correctly


            console.log(root.results());//THIS IS THE LINE IM INTERESTED IN
            console.log(root.raw.results);//this weirdly works
            //now I want to print each search results name
            root.results().each(function(result) {
                console.log("Song: " + result.get('name'));
            });

        }
    });

}
```

When I log root.results(), I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'results'

This is exactly how they do it in the docs, so does anyone know why this isnt working???

Edit: Here is the doc I was [following](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader)

Comment: Are you sure you need a separate model definition just to contain more than one SearchResult?  Why not just store your SearchResults in an array?

Comment: That makes sense to me but that isn't how they do their examples. I just added the link to the question btw

Comment: Also I plan to drill further down into this heirarchy later, I'm just trying to get this simple example working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful trial and error, I figured it out.  In the tutorial, they used unconventional model name, but in my case I needed to use the fully qualified one

So to fix I needed to change

```
hasMany  : {model: 'SearchResult', name: 'results'},
```

to

```
hasMany  : {model: 'GS.model.SearchResult', name: 'results'},
```

and same with my deeper model like this:

```
belongsTo: 'GS.model.SearchResults'
```

Tough error to catch, but I hope this can help someone else in my position

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check your error is to debug in chrome console. After callback you will find your records in root.raw or root.data.

I use to debug in chrome console and write the required code.

Comment: Yes I was doing this.  I would find that in root.raw, the data would be there.  My question is, how do I access it in sencha?  I don't want to have to manually call root.raw.xxx every time to traverse objects. I feel like this shouldn't be a hard question...